# Google Map dragend events v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Currently I have this listener event on my google maps:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() { checkBounds(); });
```

However I find that then I "throw" the map (ie on an iPhone taking and clicking the map up to scroll) the dragend happens before the map is done moving; giving me a false boundary. Is there a way to know when the bounds have stopped moving that is graceful? I know i can continue to check using the bounds_changed over and over; however was wondering if there was a cleaner way of doing this.

Cheers

Comment: *"However I find that then I "throw" the map, the dragend happens before the map is done moving"* - isn't this a bug that should be reported? Ondrag should launch after the drag is finished, which is not in this case!

Comment: I've submitted it as a bug.  I'll update SO q once a response is made.  Thank you!

Comment: Great, Frederico! Can you please post here URL to the bugreport? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the idle listener instead, although that will also fire after a zoom.