# Google map api v3 dragend event on polygon acting weird

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, draggable, polygon

I have modified a draw polygon example available at http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polygon_exampleA.html
in order to illustrate the problem. In that example, I have made the polygon draggable  and added a dragend listener. You can take a closer look at the modified code at 
http://sl.lago-consulting.com/v3_polygon_exampleA_modified.html

The dragend function worked fine until I have tried to display the lat/lon values in the path. You can uncomment and comment that last line in the function to see that the problem shows up and disappears, respectively.

I have seen a question where there seems to be a bug ([Google Map dragend events v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320384/google-map-dragend-events-v3)), but I am not sure if that is related to this case.

Any idea on how to fix this ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Please post the relevant code in your question (not just a link to your map).

Comment: Please be so kind and remove geocodezips analytics-code when you copy his examples.

Answer (score 0):

There is no bug and nothing weird, there simply is an error:

```
path.getAt(0).lon()
```

There is no method `lon()`, the name of the method is `lng()`